# Can not attach usb device using virsh

Tags: qemu, kvm

I am trying to attach ipad2 usb device by using virsh from host ubuntu 12.10 to OpenSuse 13, it returns success, but I can not find it on vm, any suggestions?

Host: ubuntu 12.10
VM: OpenSuse 13

```
===HOST===

root@o-ubuntu-103:/image# more usb_ipad2.xml 
 <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
  <source>
    <vendor id='0x05ac'/>
    <product id='0x129f'/>
  </source>
</hostdev>
root@o-ubuntu-103:/image# virsh attach-device suse13-001 usb_ipad2.xml 
Device attached successfully

root@o-ubuntu-103:/image# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 036: ID 05ac:129f Apple, Inc. iPad 2
Bus 003 Device 040: ID 04e8:6866 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

===VM===

v-suse-33:/home/aaron # lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0409:55aa NEC Corp. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0627:0001 Adomax Technology Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to attach the USB device with your VM directoly, either use the `virt-manager` GUI there is a graphical interface to add USB devices), either add line that seems as

```
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
   <source startupPolicy='optional'>
     <vendor id='0x03f0'/>
     <product id='0x4217'/>
   </source>
 </hostdev>
 <!--- TIMBER !!! this depend upon your USB device and machine would fail
                  to start if you miss, use the GUI instead! --->
```

I read this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/828823/virtual-machine-manager-error-did-not-find-usb-device